# How to remove last element from every row of a matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove the last element from every row of a matrix in javascript. I am trying to use the "map" function but I am not successful.

Here is my code:

```js
var matrixWithExtraInfo = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, "dog"],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, "dog"],
  [9, 10, 11, 12, "dog"],
  [13, 14, 15, 16, "dog"],
  [17, 18, 19, 20, "dog"]
];

var conciseMatrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16],
  [17, 18, 19, 20]
]

var conciseMatrix = matrixWithExtraInfo.map(function(index) {
  console.log(index)
  matrixWithExtraInfo[index].pop();
  return matrixWithExtraInfo[index];
});
console.log(matrixWithExtraInfo);
```

I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of undefined

Comment: map will return you the item and not the index in the first parameter - I added a console log when I made you a snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `.map` is the *item you're iterating over*, not the index.

Since each item here is an array, you can either `.pop` the array (which will *mutate* the existing array), or `.slice` the array (which will not mutate the existing array).

```js
var matrixWithExtraInfo = [
    [1,2,3,4,"dog"],
    [5,6,7,8,"dog"],
    [9,10,11,12,"dog"],
    [13,14,15,16,"dog"],
    [17,18,19,20,"dog"]
];

var conciseMatrix = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16],
    [17,18,19,20]
]

var conciseMatrix = matrixWithExtraInfo.map((arr) => {
  arr.pop();
  return arr;
});
console.log(matrixWithExtraInfo);
console.log(conciseMatrix);
```

(the above is *weird* - the structure you need is already in `matrixWithExtraInfo`, making another variable to hold it is confusing, but this is the closest to your original code)

```js
var matrixWithExtraInfo = [
    [1,2,3,4,"dog"],
    [5,6,7,8,"dog"],
    [9,10,11,12,"dog"],
    [13,14,15,16,"dog"],
    [17,18,19,20,"dog"]
];

var conciseMatrix = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16],
    [17,18,19,20]
]

var conciseMatrix = matrixWithExtraInfo.map(arr => arr.slice(0, -1));
console.log(matrixWithExtraInfo);
console.log(conciseMatrix);
```

Comment: Yep *you can either .pop the array (which will mutate the existing array), or .slice the array (which will not mutate the existing array).* First code is weird due to the mutation and creating another variable name, but it's closest to OP's original code

Comment: instead pop we should use slice if we don't want to modify original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Map will return the element so by iterating all rows we just pop the element which will remove the last element from the each row. As we need a new matrix in different array we should use slice(not pop/splice) which will return the elements in new array and not modifying original matrix.

```js
var matrixWithExtraInfo = [
    [1,2,3,4,"dog"],
    [5,6,7,8,"dog"],
    [9,10,11,12,"dog"],
    [13,14,15,16,"dog"],
    [17,18,19,20,"dog"]
];

var conciseMatrix = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16],
    [17,18,19,20]
]

var conciseMatrix = matrixWithExtraInfo.map(row => row.slice(0, row.length-1));
console.log(matrixWithExtraInfo);
console.log(conciseMatrix);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mutate the existing array, an easy way is to use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to apply [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to each element:

```js
var matrixWithExtraInfo = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, "dog"],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, "dog"],
  [9, 10, 11, 12, "dog"],
  [13, 14, 15, 16, "dog"],
  [17, 18, 19, 20, "dog"]
];

matrixWithExtraInfo.forEach(arr => arr.pop());
console.log(matrixWithExtraInfo);
```

Otherwise, just use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
var matrixWithExtraInfo = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, "dog"],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, "dog"],
  [9, 10, 11, 12, "dog"],
  [13, 14, 15, 16, "dog"],
  [17, 18, 19, 20, "dog"]
];

var conciseMatrix = matrixWithExtraInfo.map(arr => arr.slice(0, -1));
console.log(conciseMatrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `_,` in map function in your code should fix. `function(_,index)`

```js
var matrixWithExtraInfo = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, "dog"],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, "dog"],
  [9, 10, 11, 12, "dog"],
  [13, 14, 15, 16, "dog"],
  [17, 18, 19, 20, "dog"]
];

var conciseMatrix = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16],
  [17, 18, 19, 20]
]

var conciseMatrix = matrixWithExtraInfo.map(function(_,index) {
  console.log(index)
  matrixWithExtraInfo[index].pop();
  return matrixWithExtraInfo[index];
});
console.log(matrixWithExtraInfo);
```